# Local DNS Propagation?

Tags: domain-name-system

Please excuse my lack of knowledge on the topic.

I have recently made a change to a DNS record.  This change HAS propagated globally.  The changes work when I access the domain using my mobile phone, or from my home network. 2 days later, the changes STILL have not propagated on my work network.

I've flushed the DNS on my work computer using `ipconfig /flushdns`.  We are using a FortiWifi 40C router.  The router uses Primary DNS Server 8.8.8.8 (Google California) and Secondary DNS Server 208.91.112.52 (Fortinet California).  I looked up the DNS records on both servers using [this tool](http://network-tools.com/nslook/) and the changes have propagated.

I'm stuck.  My best guess would be that the office router has not updated it's DNS, and I need to manually flush it somehow.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the TTL set to on the records?

Comment: TTL was something really small.  Less than an hour.

Comment: Check the router's DNS settings. If anything, rebooting the router will flush its DNS cache.

Comment: Rebooted, didn't work.

Comment: does this affect ALL office computers or just yours? all: check if your router has a setting to override dns records. just yours: check the record is not in the hosts files of your pc (yes, unlikely, but I've seen it happen)

Comment: You should use `dig www.domain.com` or `nslookup -debug www.domain.com` (windows) to debug this. You'll be able to see which DNS server is being queried, and exactly what it's responding with, including the TTL values it has. Post the output in your question if you don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we have a local DNS server that has records for the domain in question, so accessing the domain internally produces a different result.......  I have no idea why this is in place.  The system is F^$^&#@ed here.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: That is known as split-horizon DNS. It allows you to have different DNS internally and externally (as you found out!). You may want to split the DNS to avoid going over external links, or to advertise hosts that you don't want to advertise externally (and raft of other reasons to numerous to list here...). Seems you figured it out before I got around to answering the question ;) There are a number of articles around the net going in to greater detail.